# Converting utf-8 encoded string to just plain text in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

So I've been getting all caught up in unicode and `utf-8` as i have a script which grabs images and their titles off the web. Works great, except when their title has special characters (eg. Jökulsárlón.)

it comes out as unicode :-

```
J\\xc3\\xb6kuls\\xc3\\xa1rl\\xc3\\xb3n
```

So i want a way to turn that string into plain text- whether is turning them into nearest 'normal' letters (like plain o instead of ö) or printing those actual symbols (rather than \xc3 etc.) I've tried a billion different ways, but a lot of the things i've been reading havent worked for me in python 3.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed UTF-8 but they're bytes:

```
>>> b = b'J\xc3\xb6kuls\xc3\xa1rl\xc3\xb3n'
>>> b
b'J\xc3\xb6kuls\xc3\xa1rl\xc3\xb3n'
>>> b.decode('utf-8')
'Jökulsárlón'
```

As this is Python 3.x, this is a Unicode string.

Comment: @user3662991: it works on bytes objects, not string objects. If you have a string object, something may be going wrong down the line. Or, alternatively, an encoding option needs to be set to ensure you're getting the Unicode string you need.

Answer (score 1):

`J\xc3\xb6kuls\xc3\xa1rl\xc3\xb3n` is not unicode. It may be UTF-8 though.

To turn them into Unicode you have to decode them. `s.decode('utf-8')` if it were UTF-8, for example.

Before printing or writing you have to encode them again. If you encode to ASCII, the [encode method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) accepts an option that tells it what to do with code points that cannot be represented in the given encoding.

For example: `print(s.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')`

`errors` accepts more options.

Comment: Ah yep my bad, get them confused. 

When i do that, it just returns: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'". I have a feeling that's because im on python 3 and that was used in python 2, i just dont know what the equivalent is?

Comment: Ah! It doesn't have a decode because it's str, it's already Unicode, just proceed to encode.

Comment: Thats the thing, so i have s = str(get the string here), then c = s.encode('utf-8'). and then print (c)- it still prints it with \xc2\ etc. :(

Comment: Try this: print(s.encode('ascii', errors='ignore'). There are more options for `errors`.

Comment: No luck. Still the same un-decoded /x15 etc. throughout :(. Thanks for your help anyway, doesnt look like its going to cooperate. I'll have to find a workaround

Comment: Please, in an interpreter, try this exactly: `'J\xc3\xb6kuls\xc3\xa1rl\xc3\xb3n'.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')`

Answer (score 1):

If your string is `<class 'str'>` and it prints literally `J\\xc3\\xb6kuls\\xc3\\xa1rl\\xc3\\xb3n`, then the last line below will decode it:

```
>>> s='J\\xc3\\xb6kuls\\xc3\\xa1rl\\xc3\\xb3n'
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> s
'J\\xc3\\xb6kuls\\xc3\\xa1rl\\xc3\\xb3n'
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'Jökulsárlón'
```

How it got that convoluted is unknown. If this isn't the solution, then update your question with the type of the variable holding the string (`type(s)` for example) and the exact value as shown above for my example.